# How to Free Resources when DLL is Unloaded or Process Terminates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc, resources

When my MFC DLL is loaded a class is instantiated in `dllmain`.  How do I free the resources allocated for this when the DLL is unloaded or its process completes?  Will this be done automatically by the system?  I am using Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding this question: isn't that what the standard `atexit` function is made for ? I know that the standard doesn't talk about dll, so I am more speaking about compiler behavior here wrt to this method.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Submit that as your answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you dll main function just handle a case for the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HMODULE hDll, DWORD dwReason, PVOID pvReserved ) {
  switch ( dwReason ) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      // the dll is being detached, do you clean up here
      break;
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that some things are not possible inside of DllMain(), so you want to keep whatever yo do there very quick and simple.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like a good solution, but my DLL entry point looks like this: `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])`.  It is an MFC DLL generated in Visual Studio 2008 by going to New Project -> Win32 Project -> and selecting DLL, Extensions, and MFC as the options.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `new`-ing and storing of pointer in global `T*` variable, with a global `T` variable.

That lets the automatic C++ machinery do the work for you.

On DLL unload the destructor is called automatically.

Note: supporting DLL loading and unloading from multiple threads, may be more difficult.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Are you sure this works if the DLL loads and unloads multiple times?

Comment: @Steve: one can never guarantee that there isn't Yet Another Bug in Visual C++ (and this is compiler dependent, the C++ Holy Standard has nothing to say about dynamic libraries). So if that was an issue then I'd test it. Good point.